# OnEditorActionListener with imeOptions actionNext not working

Tags: android, imeoptions

Here is my code:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/mylayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/some_layout">
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/myid"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="@string/some_hint"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:inputType="time"
            android:maxLength="@integer/max_input_length"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textSize="15sp"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

and the Java code:

```
myField = (TextInputEditText) findViewById(R.id.myid);
    myField.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            boolean handled = false;
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT) {
                Log.d(TAG,"next");
                //Do something
                handled = true;
            }
            Log.d(TAG,"handled: "+handled);
            return handled;
        }
    });`
```

Unfortunately when I press the next button on the keyboard nothing happens. The cursor doesn't jump to the next field.
I can't see what I am missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per doc

> IME_ACTION_NEXT
>
> Bits of IME_MASK_ACTION: the action key performs a "next" operation,
>   taking the user to the next field that will accept text.

So it means it will focus on next focusable object like edittext or auto complete text view. so if no other object can get focus it will not move focus.

Comment: Hi @androidnoobdev, the object is a `TextInputLayout ` just like the one above. So I think it should be able to get focus.

Comment: @DeKekem then add this attributes - android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true" and check now.

Comment: ALSO; AND THIS IS A HUGE BUG: IME_ACTION_NEXT does not cause jump to the next field if this field is hidden behind the soft keyboard. I have sent a bug report to ANDROID R/D today.

Answer (score 2):

use `android:inputType="text"` for your `TextInputEditText`

try calling `view.requestFocus();` in your action .

```
myField.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        boolean handled = false;
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT) {
            Log.d(TAG,"next");
            //Do something
            Log.d(TAG,"handled: "+handled);
            view.requestFocus() ;  //add focus to next view object
            return true;   //return true
        }
        Log.d(TAG,"handled: "+handled);
        return false;   //add return
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi @rafsanahmad007. I do set handled=true for my particular action which is then returned by the method.